# What is the common ratio of an infinite geometric series if the sum is $8$ and the sum of the first $4$ terms is $5\frac{15}{32}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the common ratio of an infinite geometric series if the sum is $8$ and the sum of the first $4$ terms is $5\frac{15}{32}$?

We basically have $$S=\dfrac{a_1}{1-q}=8$$ and $$a_1+a_1q+a_1q^2+a_1q^3=a_1(1+q+q^2+q^3)\\=a_1(1+q+q^2(1+q))=a_1(1+q)(q^2+1)=\dfrac{5\cdot32+15}{32}=\dfrac{160+15}{32}=\dfrac{175}{32}$$

Diving the second by the first ($a_1\ne0)$ gives $$(1-q)(1+q)(1+q^2)=\dfrac{175}{32\cdot8}=\dfrac{175}{256}\\(1-q^2)(1+q^2)=\dfrac{175}{256}\\q^4=\dfrac{256-175}{256}=\dfrac{81}{256}\Leftrightarrow q=\pm\dfrac{3}{4}$$ Both $q_1$ and $q_2$ are in the interval $(-1;1)$. The authors wrote only $q=\dfrac34$ as an answer. Why so?

Comment: @Ajay, the real solutions of $q^4=\dfrac{81}{256}$ are $q=\pm\dfrac{3}{4}$. Who said it worked the same way?

Comment: I get $a_1 = 2, \; \; q = \frac{3}{4}  $   or $a_1 = 14, \; \; q = \frac{-3}{4}  $    worth checking both

Comment: Sadly, even good authors sometimes forget to exclude negative values for parameters. If $q$ is allowed to be complex (or quaternionic or whatever), which the problem statement doesn't preclude, we get even more options.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a typo or they are limiting to $q>0$, indeed, for $q=-\frac34$ we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_1\cdot \left(-\frac 34\right)^k =8 \implies a_1=14$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^3 14\cdot \left(-\frac 34\right)^k = 14\cdot\frac{1-\left(-\frac 34\right)^4}{1+\frac34} =\frac{175}{32}$$

therefore also this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Both $(a_1,q)=(2,3/4)$ and $(a_1,q)=(14,-3/4)$ are valid answers.
This can be easily checked by plugging in those values into the first two equations.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said using both $q = 3/4$ and $q=-3/4$ give valid results.

For $q = 3/4$ we have $a_1 = 2$:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n = 8$$
$$ S_4 = 2 + 2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^1 + 2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 + 2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3 = \frac{175}{32}$$

For $q = -3/4$ we have $a_1 = 14$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 14\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^n = 8$$
$$ S_4 = 14 + 14\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^1 + 14\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 + 14\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^3 = \frac{175}{32}$$